# Import order in python for specific packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, isort

I ran pylint on my codebase and it complained that `from config import ConfigParser` was defined before `from pathlib import Path` Why is this the case?

When I ran isort of the file, it agreed with pylint. From what I understand it groups imports by type

- Native to python
- General 3rd party
- local packages

And in that it groups them by whether or not you use `from` or `import` and after that it wants them alphabetical.

I would have thought that config would come before pathlib, but this is not the case. What is happening here?

## Before running isort

```py
from config import ConfigParser
from pathlib import Path
```

## After running isort

```py
from pathlib import Path

from config import ConfigParser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `isort` [docs](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/custom_sections_and_ordering.html) the default order is the following:

1. [Future](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__future__-module-in-python/)
2. stdlib (`pathlib` is from stdlib)
3. Third-party modules
4. First-party modules
5. Local modules (like `config`)

This way `isort` first orders imports by their *category*, then orders them *alphabetically* or by length.

Answer (score 0):

The stdlib module is called `configparser`, so you should change your imports to:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
from pathlib import Path
```

and isort will behave as you expect.